# jasmine spy on nested object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

My service object looks like this:

```
var appService = {
 serviceOne: {
   get: function(){}
 },
 serviceTwo: {
  query: function(){}
 }
}
```

I would like to mock appService,something like:

```
expect(appService.serviceTwo.query).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

How would I go about doing it?

Comment: You should accept an answer.  There are 2 here that work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OK I got this working with this:

```
appService: {
  serviceOne: jasmine.createSpyObj('serviceOne', ['get']),
  serviceTwo: jasmine.createSpyObj('serviceTwo', ['query'])
}
```

I hope it is the right way to do.

Comment: This is the optimal approach. In it, both `'get'` and `'query'` are spy methods. Thus, something like `expect(appService.serviceTwo.query).toHaveBeenCalled()` is available.

Answer (score 6):

Just replace the function with jasmine spies:

```
var appService = {
  serviceOne: {
    get: jasmine.createSpy()
  },
  serviceTwo: {
    query: jasmine.createSpy()
  }
}
```

later on:

```
expect(appService.serviceTwo.query).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Comment: What if you wanted to `spyOn` instead of doing this - is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a very similar problem and got a solution to work that allows spying at multiple levels relatively easily.

```
appService = {
  serviceOne: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue({
    get: jasmine.createSpy()
  },
  serviceTwo: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue({
    query: jasmine.createSpy()
  }
}
```

This solution allows the following code to be called in a unit test

```
expect(appService.serviceOne).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foobar');
expect(appService.serviceOne().get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('some', 'params');
```

Note: this code has not been tested; however, I have a very simmilar implementation in one of my apps. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The examples above show explicit, named spy creation. However, one can simply continue chaining in the `jasmine.spyOn` function to get to the method level.

For a deeply nested object:

```
var appService = {
 serviceOne: {
   get: function(){}
 }
};

jasmine.spyOn(appService.serviceOne, 'get');

expect(appService.serviceOne.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
```